# Символ переноса строки в заголовках HTTP

Tags: c++, веб-программирование, http, веб-сервер, backend

Передаю следующих ответ от сервера:

```
QString response = "HTTP/1.1 \r\n Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * \r\n 200 OK \r\n\r\n";
```

Я не до конца понимаю куда именно в ответ "засовывать" параметр Access-Control-Allow-Origin и правильно ли я указал символы переноса строки

Answer (score 3):

Сначала status line, потом заголовки, потом пустая строка.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK<CRLF>
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *<CRLF>
<CRLF>
```

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP